# template Integrate in Sylius method?

Tags: sylius

I can not integrate a template after installing the setup on my machine.

I had put the template in folder i.e `app >  Resources > views > Front end > layout.html.twig`

I got the template but not getting cascading style sheets files for this
template while saved those Cascading style sheets and java script
and other file in WEB folder of my project.

How can I implement this template?

Answer (score 0):

The template I think you're looking for is located in:

```
src/Sylius/Bundle/WebBundle/Resources/views/Frontend/layout.html.twig
```

Comment: I had made a file layout.html.twig file in src/Sylius/Bundle/WebBundle/Resources/views/Frontend/layout.html.twig.
That you are talking about. But i cannot see any changes in layout.html.twig when i changed in this twig file .

Comment: i just want to implement the Ecommerce template in Sylius from scratch.
Because i implement the methods and trick to integrate template and to run the template in Sylius .

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answer suggested, try putting the template in folder: `app >  Resources > SyliusWebBundle > views > Frontend > layout.html.twig`

Comment: after implementing your methid i am not able to call an CSS and Js .
While i had already store template CSS , Jss in WEB folder for project ..

Comment: How do you call both, can you paste the code please?

Comment: i just put the template i.e index file of template in layout.html file that u told me and after that i had copy and paste all other css and js file of that templae in WEB folder ..
There is no coding write know